# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when sending post request for /login, Spring boot Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to make a Spring boot project JWT authorisation. I am following Amigoscode Spring Boot and Spring Security with JWT including Access and Refresh Tokens.

When I make a post request for http://localhost:8080/login from postman using the x-www-form-urlencoded, passing the username and password as key and their values.

I get a long error. I tried debugging but no help.

The error I get in console is :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:172) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
```

Line 201 of Provider Manager(Have commented the line number in the method) :

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    Class<? extends Authentication> toTest = authentication.getClass();
    AuthenticationException lastException = null;
    AuthenticationException enter code hereparentException = null;
    Authentication result = null;
    Authentication parentResult = null;
    int currentPosition = 0;
    int size = this.providers.size();
    for (AuthenticationProvider provider : getProviders()) {
        if (!provider.supports(toTest)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace(LogMessage.format("Authenticating request with %s (%d/%d)",
                    provider.getClass().getSimpleName(), ++currentPosition, size));
        }
        try {
            result = provider.authenticate(authentication);
            if (result != null) {
                copyDetails(authentication, result);
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (AccountStatusException | InternalAuthenticationServiceException ex) {
            prepareException(ex, authentication);
            // SEC-546: Avoid polling additional providers if auth failure is due to
            // invalid account status
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            lastException = ex;
        }
    }
    if (result == null && this.parent != null) {
        // Allow the parent to try.
        try {
/*Line 201*/            parentResult = this.parent.authenticate(authentication);
            result = parentResult;
        }
        catch (ProviderNotFoundException ex) {
            // ignore as we will throw below if no other exception occurred prior to
            // calling parent and the parent
            // may throw ProviderNotFound even though a provider in the child already
            // handled the request
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            parentException = ex;
            lastException = ex;
        }
    }
    if (result != null) {
        if (this.eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication && (result instanceof CredentialsContainer)) {
            // Authentication is complete. Remove credentials and other secret data
            // from authentication
            ((CredentialsContainer) result).eraseCredentials();
        }
        // If the parent AuthenticationManager was attempted and successful then it
        // will publish an AuthenticationSuccessEvent
        // This check prevents a duplicate AuthenticationSuccessEvent if the parent
        // AuthenticationManager already published it
        if (parentResult == null) {
            this.eventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Parent was null, or didn't authenticate (or throw an exception).
    if (lastException == null) {
        lastException = new ProviderNotFoundException(this.messages.getMessage("ProviderManager.providerNotFound",
                new Object[] { toTest.getName() }, "No AuthenticationProvider found for {0}"));
    }
    // If the parent AuthenticationManager was attempted and failed then it will
    // publish an AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent
    // This check prevents a duplicate AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent if the
    // parent AuthenticationManager already published it
    if (parentException == null) {
        prepareException(lastException, authentication);
    }
    throw lastException;
}
```

Line 510 of WebSecurityConfigurer(Have commented the Line number in the method) :

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (this.delegate != null) {
/*Line 510*/            return this.delegate.authenticate(authentication);
        }
        synchronized (this.delegateMonitor) {
            if (this.delegate == null) {
                this.delegate = this.delegateBuilder.getObject();
                this.delegateBuilder = null;
            }
        }
        return this.delegate.authenticate(authentication);
    }
```

My Web Security Configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

}
```

The Custom Authentication Filter class is :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();  // getPRincipal will return us the user that is successfully authenticated.
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
    String access_token = JWT.create()
            .withSubject(user.getUsername())
            .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10*60*1000))
            .withIssuer(request.getRequestURI().toString())
            .withClaim("roles", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .sign(algorithm);
    
    String refresh_token = JWT.create()
            .withSubject(user.getUsername())
            .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 60 * 1000))
            .withIssuer(request.getRequestURI().toString())
            .sign(algorithm);
    
    response.setHeader("access_token", access_token);
    response.setHeader("refresh_token", refresh_token);
}

}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: There is no need to write custom JWT support, since Spring Security supports this out of the box. You can see a sample provided by the team [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login).

Comment: Could you show the line 201 in ProviderManager.java and 510 in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java? Would be easier to see where the loop is.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thank you for your time to reply, I'll check this out immediately. But since I've already done most of the work here, would be nice to know where the problem persists

Comment: @grekier thank you for your time to check this out, I'll edit the question and add the lines.

Comment: Basically you are calling the child (`this.delegate.authenticate`) which calls tis parent (`this.parent.authenticate`) and it goes in a loop. Hence Overflow. I can't see the fix right away on where the auth is wrong but you cannot have both call the other.

Comment: @grekier
I think I have the similar issue in my spring boot microservice example. As I still couldn't fix the issue, it is possible to help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-servicetest-and-controllertest-for-junit-throwing-ja